# Importing notebooks with definitions that cause messages during formatting

Tags: bugs, import, warning-messages, notebooks

According to [reference pages](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html?view=all), `Quiet` "does not quiet messages that occur during formatting", which typically is just a nuisance, but it seems to affect `NotebookImport`.

Consider this definition that uses `NumberForm`, which is mentioned in the ref page of `Quiet` as exactly raising such format message:

```
exportForm[{l_,r_}][n_]:= StandardForm[NumberForm[n,{l,r},ExponentFunction->(Null&)]];
```

If the above is saved in a notebook and then the input is imported:

```
 NotebookImport["~/Desktop/example-notebook.nb", "Input"]
```

the definition changes - note the right hand side displays as `n`

```
{HoldComplete[exportForm[{l_,r_}][n_]:=n;]}
```

While the full form shows the definition

```
 NotebookImport["~/Desktop/example-notebook.nb", "Input"] // FullForm
```

> List[HoldComplete[CompoundExpression[SetDelayed[exportForm[List[Pattern[l,Blank[]],Pattern[r,Blank[]]]][Pattern[n,Blank[]]],StandardForm[NumberForm[n,List[l,r],Rule[ExponentFunction,Function[Null]]]]],Null]]]

However, this seems to interfere with subsequent processing.

In addition the message appears:

```
NumberForm::iprf: Formatting specification {l,r} should be a positive integer or a pair of positive integers.
```

This message is not raised when the function is actually defined,
so the behavior seems like a bug. Is there a workaround or a way to apply `Quiet` to such "loud" definitions?